# How to overwrite extracted zip file in C#, WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, extract, restore, zip

I have this code that backup and restore in C# using MS Access as its database. I finished doing the backup in zip format and now I want to restore the Zipped file. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
public void BackupDatabase(string dateToday)
    {

        string dbFileName = "dbCPS.accdb";
            string CurrentDatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory , dbFileName);
            string backTimeStamp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dbFileName) + "_" + dateToday + ".zip";// +Path.GetExtension(dbFileName);
            string destFileName = backTimeStamp;// +dbFileName;
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string PathtobackUp = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString();
                destFileName = Path.Combine(PathtobackUp, destFileName);

                //File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, destFileName, true);
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddFile(dbFileName);
                    zip.Save(destFileName);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Backup successful! ");                  
            }            
    }

private void backupToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        BackupDatabase(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy_HH.mm"));
    }


public void RestoreDatabase(string restoreFile)
    {
        string dbFileName = "dbCPS.accdb";
        string pathBackup = restoreFile;
        string CurrentDatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, dbFileName);
        File.Copy(pathBackup, CurrentDatabasePath, true);
        MessageBox.Show("Restore successful! "); 
    }

private void restoreToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            openFileDialogBackUp.FileName = "dbCPS";
            openFileDialogBackUp.InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Sauvegardes";
            if (openFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                RestoreDatabase(openFileDialogBackUp.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This code extracts the zipped file but I dont know how to do the restore at the same time.

```
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(restoreFile))
        {
            zip.ExtractAll(CurrentDatabasePath);
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the open database used by your program? Or it is just a problem to find the correct destination path and write the extracted file over the previous one?

Comment: @Steve Yes im trying to overwrite the open database. Since its function is restore.

Comment: the code is working if im gonna restore the .accdb file but when I restore the zip, theres an error. I think it means I need to Extract first before using this code "File.Copy(pathBackup, CurrentDatabasePath, true);". My error when I use this is code "using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(restoreFile))
        {
            zip.ExtractAll(CurrentDatabasePath);
        }" is the file is open so I cant overwrite?

Comment: What library or reference are you using to use the ZipFile functions? I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: @Meta Have you found it? Its Ionic.Zip. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it! For those who are in need of the code, here it is:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(pathBackup))
        {
            zip.ExtractAll(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite directly the database while you are actively using it.
By actively I mean you have an `OleDbConnection` open on that database.

From your code above it is not possible to understand if you are in this situation, so the first thing to do is to search for all occurences of an OleDbConnection and check if they are closed correctly. If you have a global OleDbConnection that it is kept open for the lifetime of your application (a very bad practice), then you need to close it before trying to overwrite the accdb file

```
public void RestoreDatabase(string restoreFile)
{
    string dbFileName = "dbCPS.accdb";
    string extractedFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    string CurrentDatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, dbFileName);
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(restoreFile))
    {
        // Extract to a temporary name built by the Framework for you....
        zip.ExtractAll(extractedFile);
    }

    // Now, before copying over the accdb file, you need to be sure that there is no
    // open OleDbConnection to this file, otherwise the IOException occurs because you
    // cannot change that file while it is actively used by a OleDbConnection

    // something like global_conn.Close(); global_conn.Dispose();

    File.Copy(extractedFile, CurrentDatabasePath, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Restore successful! "); 

    // and then reopen the connection

}
```

Comment: Ive done that code before. Anyway this is the error. Cannot create "filename.zip" because a file or directory with the same name already exist.

Comment: Anyway what can you say about this code?
`using(ZipFile zip= ZipFile.Read(ZipFileToExtract))
{
    zip.ExtractExistingFile= ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently;
    zip.ExtractAll(TargetDirectory);
}`

Comment: Ive dont it. Just added this code. Thanks anyways! :)
`zip.ExtractAll(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btn_UodateMembers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bwUpdateMembers.IsBusy)
    {
        bwUpdateMembers.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}

private string ExtractZip(FileInfo fi)
{
    string extractTo = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fi.FullName))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry ze in zip)
        {
            ze.Extract(extractTo, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }

    return extractTo;
}

public FileInfo GetLatestFile(DirectoryInfo di)
{
    FileInfo fi = di.GetFiles()
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.CreationTime)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return fi;
}

private void bwUpdateMembers_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Ghost Wolf\\Desktop\\zip";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    if (di != null)
    {
        FileInfo fi = GetLatestFile(di);
        string folder = ExtractZip(fi);
        MessageBox.Show("Your'e Files Have Been Extracted", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

PLEASE TELL ME IF THIS WORKED FOR YOU!!